# EditText box changes based on text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, I have a form with name, email id, mobile etc. I took edit text boxes for each text view.

Now, I want all the edit text boxes to be equal size. Based on the text, the edit text box changes.

Can anyone help?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#339999">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact Form"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name :"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/fname" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name :"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/lname" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile No :"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/mobile" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alternate No :"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/altno" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email Id :"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comments :"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<EditText 

    android:id="@+id/coment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:singleLine="true">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<Button 
    android:text="Send" 
    android:id="@+id/Send" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set weight for textview and edittext also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#339999"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Contact Form"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="First Name :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Last Name :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Mobile No :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Alternate No :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/altno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Email Id :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Comments :"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/coment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the EditText views to be single line, try the attribute `android:maxLines="1"`. I think `singleLine` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Androids [TableLayouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). Basically a TableLayout works like a table in HTML. It assures that all elements of a column have the exact same width.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you better to use tableLayout or GridLayout.

For example with TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    android:background="#339999">

    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Contact Form" 
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:layout_span="3" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
                android:textSize="25sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fname" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
            android:cursorVisible="true" 
            android:layout_span="2" 
            android:padding="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#123123" 
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="First Name :" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:padding="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
            android:textSize="15sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lname" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
            android:cursorVisible="true" 
            android:padding="5dp" 
            android:layout_span="2" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#123123" 
            android:singleLine="true">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```